# Por questão de experiência do usuário, botões de confirmação devem ficar a direita ou esquerda?

Tags: ux

Estou com essa dúvida. Estamos montando um sistema onde existe um modal que faz um questionamento ao usuário se ele deseja efetuar tal operação ou não.

A minha dúvida surgiu em relação à posição do botão de confirmação, se ele dever ficar à direita ou à esquerda, por conta da experiência do usuário.

Sempre costumo colocar o botão "Sim" à direta se os botões estiverem alinhados à direita, e à esquerda se estiver alinhado à esquerda.

Exemplo:

```html
<div style="text-align:right">
<button>Não</button>
<button>Sim</button>
</div>

<div style="text-align:left">
<button>Sim</button>
<button>Não</button>
</div>
```

Porém esse é um padrão que "aprendi sozinho". Mas me preocupo com a questão da experiência do usuário.

Atualmente tenho um modal que está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, como os botões estão centralizados, fico na dúvida qual seria a melhor alinhamento do botão "Sim", para melhorar a experiência do usuário.

Então, tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- Por questão de experiência do usuário, botões de confirmação deve ficar a direita ou esquerda?
- O alinhamento dos botões influenciaria onde eu deveria alinhá-los?
- Alinhamento de botões centralizados, o botão "Sim", por conta da experiência do usuário, deveria ser alinhado à direita?

Comment: Importante leitura: http://tableless.com.br/padroes-de-ux-mal/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Introdução necessária

Antes de mais nada, um esclarecimento sobre o que é uma "questão de experiência de usuário" (caso contrário, todo o conteúdo aqui fica simplesmente genérico de mais a ponto de receber votos para fechamento ou argumentos equivocados de que é apenas [baseado em opiniões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104044/por-quest%C3%A3o-de-experi%C3%AAncia-do-usu%C3%A1rio-bot%C3%B5es-de-confirma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-devem-ficar-a-direi#comment213089_104055)). Considere o seguinte diagrama (baseado no livro *[Designing Pleasurable Products](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=0s3el8sDjHsC&redir_esc=y)*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa pirâmide é diretamente inspirada na [Pirâmide de Maslow](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarquia_de_necessidades_de_Maslow), só que ao invés de tratar das necessidades primárias dos seres humanos de forma geral trata das necessidades primárias dos seres humanos *em relação a um produto* qualquer. A ideia é que existe uma hierarquia de importância, de forma que a função (funcionalidade) de um produto é o mais imediatamente relevante, seguido do quão fácil é sua utilização (usabilidade) e por fim do quão agradável é utilizá-lo (prazer). A experiência do usuário é o resultado *de todos esses níveis* quando um produto (no nosso caso, um produto de software) é utilizado por uma pessoa.

### Posicionamento de botões

A sua pergunta é essencialmente sobre o posicionamento dos botões. Mas, no exemplo que você fornece, não há uma resposta imediatamente correta. Você menciona o seguinte:

> "Sempre costumo colocar o botão "Sim" à direta se os botões estiverem
>   alinhados à direita, e à esquerda se estiver alinhado à esquerda."

Isso também não tem nada necessariamente errado, a não ser que você faça essas distinções em um mesmo sistema de software ou em uma mesma família de aplicações. Se você quer facilitar o uso por parte dos seus usuários (segundo nível na pirâmide - usabilidade), é bom manter o mesmo padrão em toda a aplicação.

Então, nesse caso, escolha um padrão e use-o sempre. Eu diria que como a nossa escrita/leitura (ocidental) é realizada da esquerda para a direita e de cima para baixo, talvez faça sentido deixar o botão mais relevante à frente do outro (por "à frente", significa mais à direita/acima), já que ele vai ser lido primeiro. Mas na realidade isso importa pouco em decisões binárias, pois o usuário ainda vai precisar parar para ler e entender a pergunta, e também ler ambas as opções disponíveis para tomar sua decisão. Nesse aspecto, o uso de padrão só facilita porque se o usuário confiar que o padrão é mantido, ele pode ler apenas a mensagem e então clicar seguramente no botão apropriado usando apenas o critério direita/esquerda ou cima/baixo.

### Outras questões que podem ser mais relevantes

Além do posicionamento (que é o que você efetivamente pergunta), há outros aspectos que podem ser relevantes para a experiência do usuário na sua interface e que você não menciona (talvez porque sequer os tenha notado). São eles:

1. **Cores**. A interação no seu sistema é baseada em mouse e/ou toque, ou o usuário utiliza alguma outra forma? Se a interação depende de clique do mouse ou toque com os dedos, a definição de cores tem pouco impacto. No seu exemplo você só estaria enfatizando o botão "Sim", mas o usuário tem pouco o que duvidar. Mas, imagina um sistema em que o usuário utiliza as setas do teclado (ou o botão direcional de um joystick em um videogame) para mudar a "seleção" do botão ativo, e então pressiona ENTER (ou o botão X) para ativar a seleção atual. Nesse caso, a escolha de cores é fundamental para evitar confusões. **Principalmente em escolhas binárias!** Se eu tenho apenas duas opções de cores distintas, e ao pressionar uma seta a "seleção" muda de uma para a outra, como eu faço para saber qual está de fato selecionada? Na sua imagem de exemplo, o que significaria seleção num contexto desse? É a cor mais escura (gradiente vermelho), ou é a cor mais clara (cinza)? No seu exemplo o usuário talvez possa inferir que é a cor mais escura dado o fato de que todo o entorno é mais claro, mas essa indicação seria muito mais claramente dada se ao mudar a seleção uma animação literalmente movesse a "caixa de seleção" mais lentamente de uma opção para a outra. Em decisões que não são binárias esse problema é menos crítico, porque o usuário percebe pela mudança de seleção que há apenas uma dentre muitas opções que é de fato diferente.
2. **Interrupção desnecessária**. Uma caixa de diálogo desse tipo tem o objetivo de perguntar ao usuário uma informação relevante ou de evitar que ele cometa erros. O exemplo clássico disso é no MS Word, quando você digitou todo o seu TCC, *ainda não gravou as alterações*, e clica no menu "sair". O software te interrompe e pergunta se você realmente deseja sair sem gravar, prevenindo assim que você cometa um erro terrível e tenha uma péssima experiência de uso. Mas, isso não quer dizer que o uso de caixas de diálogo deve ser um padrão usado indiscrimidamente. Uma pergunta que você deve se fazer é: essa interrupção é realmente relevante no processo de uso? Por exemplo, eu uso um aplicativo de lanterna no meu celular que todas as vezes que eu escolho a opção "sair" ele me interrompe com a pergunta: "Você tem certeza que deseja sair?". E eu penso: "Não! Eu só cliquei em 'sair' porque eu estava com saudades de ler essa mensagem!". Isso é muito chato em momentos em que eu quero rapidamente alternar entre aplicações. Não há perigo algum em me deixar prosseguir imediatamente com a ação, pois não há potencial perda de nada. No seu caso, a primeira parte da mensagem tem um pouco esse caráter ("Tem certeza que deseja fazer o que você acabou de solicitar?"), e talvez apenas a segunda parte tenha algum fundamento de proteção na usabilidade (novamente, segundo nível da pirâmide). Mas, há formas mais agradáveis de fazer essa proteção (movendo agora para o terceiro nível da pirâmide - prazer). Por exemplo, supondo que a conferência de produtos tenha sido feita em um formulário anterior e precisa ser atestada pelo usuário, você pode utilizar um checkbox que somente quando selecionado habilite o botão de continuar. E assim, você evita uma caixa de diálogo totalmente desnecessária e disruptiva.
3. **Aproveitamento de espaço**. A ideia de centralizar os botões é passar ao usuário uma sensação de aproveitamento de espaço. Isso está relacionado com às nossas capacidades de percepção. Quando uma caixa de diálogo é exibida, nosso olhar percorre primeiramente a parte mais central e só então vaga para as demais áreas periféricas (sendo atraído então por signos mais constrastantes). Vale a pena fazer uma análise da área disponível versus o tamanho das mensagens de texto exibidas. Talvez seja possível aumentar o tamanho dos botões e da fonte de seus textos, para facilitar também para usuários com dificuldades de leitura.

Answer (score 7):

### Quais são as melhores práticas no alinhamento dos botões ?

Esta questão vária de *layout* para *layout* mas você pode notar que os botões de modais são alinhados a direita, os botões devem ser organizados por ordem de importância, digo por utilização, imagine a inserção de um *post* em uma rede social. Ele destacará o botão *Post*  mais a direita do que o Cancelar, isto por que ele entende que será a ação mais provável do usuário.

Este mesmo conceito pode ser levado para outros tipos de *layout* como por exemplo um formulário com vários passos (*steps*), geralmente são utilizados botões a direita informando Próximo, ou Prosseguir.

Botões alinhados a esquerda são geralmente utilizados para concluir uma ação, exemplo formulário de contato.

#### Quando é bom alinhar os botões ao centro?

É interessante alinhar ao centro quando você quiser destacar alguma informação. Por exemplo, se você deixar o seu Sim/Não 30% maior e colocar um texto chamativo.

Aconselhado: Identificar os casos citados acima e alinhar o seu *layout* conforme cada situação, é ruim entrar em um sistema que possui botões alinhados na esquerda,direita e centro.
Padronizar ajuda bastante.

Recomendação: [*User Experience - What are the best practices of button alignment?*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/what-are-the-best-practices-of-button-alignment)

Comment: Você ajudou o amigo do modal a mudar de opnião ;)

Answer (score 6):

Se tratando de UX, para uma melhor experiência de usuário, as disposições dos elementos devem ser posicionadas de maneira a guiar o usuário para uma melhor resposta.

O usuário não pode ser indagado ou instigado a executar uma ação em certas situações como essa. Por exemplo, nós lemos da esquerda para a direita e obviamente dois botões um "Vermelho" e um branco, mesmo que eu queira clicar no branco me instiga a clicar no vermelho. Então, primeiramente os botões deveriam ser da mesma cor porque assim o usuário não será influenciado na ação. Sobre estar no lado esquerdo ou direito acredito não ter problema se as cores estiverem iguais porque repetindo, assim você joga a decisão para o usuário sem intervenção.

Comment: Concordo que o importante é guiar o usuário para uma melhor resposta. E por isso mesmo às vezes o que é necessário é sim influenciar o usuário na ação. Um exemplo são as confirmações de operações perigosas, que precisam transmitir a ideia de que são destrutivas, mas sem "instigar" o usuário a escolhê-la. (PS: o -1 não fui eu ;))

Comment: "Deseja dropar o banco de dados" deveria estar em qual lado @bfavaretto? kkkkk

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo com você sim e acredito então que depende do objetivo da ação, no caso dessa modal não deveria influênciar porque o usuário precisa conferir os produtos antes de clicar em um dos botões. pois esta escrito "você tem certeza que deseja confirmar o recebimento...".

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia pesquisar mais sobre IHC (interação humano computador), porém desde já te adianto que não existe uma reposta certa para sua pergunta, suas perguntas são extremamente variáveis. Pois o foco é a experiência do usuário.

Os usuários podem estar acessando de localidades diferentes, podem ser de culturas diferentes, podem utilizar sistemas de escrita diferentes, dispositivos distintos e até mesmo o fato de ser destro ou canhoto pode influenciar a experiência do usuário (não estou dizendo que o web-designer deve magicamente saber de tudo isso ou prever todas as possibilidades).

Isso sem falar na questão das paletas de cores, alinhamento, tipografia e outras coisas afins de design.

Falar que um elemento deve ficar em uma coordenada específica é simplesmente opinião, teoria. Na prática, o importante é ser intuitivo e coerente (manter um padrão).

Comment: Sobre ser destro e canhoto: Não tem como o desenvolvedor advinhar isso. Em relação as outras culturas, eu concordo em partes, pois geralmente alguns sistemas são desenvolvidos para "o mundo", e outros "para a localidade"